# Showing correlation is between $-1$ and $1$

Tags: statistics, covariance

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables, then $E(X_1^2)E(X_2^2) \geq [E(X_1X_2)]^2$ by Schwarz's inequality. Use this fact to show that $-1 \leq \rho_{12} \leq 1$.

I know that $\rho_{12} = \frac{(E(X_1X_2) - E(X_1)E(X_2))}{ \sqrt{(E(X_1^2) - E(X_1)^2)(E(X_2^2) -E(X_2)^2)}}$

But I am stuck from this point on. I believe I need to show that the denominator is always smaller than the denominator, which would show that it would never be greater than 1. Squaring the whole thing gives me some $E(X_1^2)E(X_2^2)$ and $[E(X_1X_2)]^2$ terms in the numerator, which were mentioned in the inequality, but the rest gets really ugly.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the **definition** of the variance of $X$ is $\text{Var}(X)=E((X-\mu_X)^2)$. Your version $E(X^2)-(\mu_X)^2$ happens to be often more computationally convenient. It is not hard to show they are equal.

Similarly, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is *defined* as $E((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y))$. Your version is equivalent, and the equivalence is not hard to prove.

If you use the definitions of variance and covariance, the result follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarz.

If you want to use the formulas for variance and covariance that you quoted, a first step is to prove the equivalence to the basic definitions. Or else you can show that variance and covariance are preserved by shifts, and shift so as to make the means $0$.

Comment: Did you preview your LaTeX?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why I need to show that the two definitions are equivalent? The book I am using gives the equation that I used in my first post, so I figured it was safe to use it.

Comment: @user21820: I am having trouble with preview, and only see the compiled version after I post.

Comment: @N-C: Probably it is not the *only* equation it gives for variance and covariance. The formulas I quoted make the proof that $|\rho|\le 1$ straight Cauchy-Schwarz, since from CS we get $E((X-\mu_X)^2)E((Y-\mu_Y)^2)\ge [E((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y))]^2$.

Comment: Ah I see. It must be hard when you've a long post and plenty of formulae!

Comment: @user21820: It is a recent problem, I think MathJax has changed. Another side effect is that every few minutes I get a notice that some process is running and asks whether I want it to stop. Only on one of my computers, the Windows one is fine.

Comment: Did you try using a different browser? I'm using an extremely old version of Firefox and yet everything works (except chat).

Comment: @user21820: On the by now vintage Mac, I use a recently and automatically updated version of Firefox.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I am understanding now. But to get those CS equations, I'd need to square the correlation, correct? So I'd get $-1 \leq p_{12}^2 \leq 1$, but I need to state that for $p_{12}$. It isn't legal to take the square root here, since there is a negative number in the inequality?

Comment: Haha sorry for the off-topic discussion, but anyway did you see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/minor-nag-with-mathjax-freezing-computer? I don't have the problem so I can't really help though!

Comment: @N-C: You don't get $-1 \le ρ^2 \le 1$; you get $0 \le ρ^2 \le 1$ because the right-hand expression in André's comment above is non-negative, and then you can take square roots.

Comment: @user21820 Wait, but then that is showing that $0 \leq p \leq 1$, which is not what I wanted. How do I show the -1 part of the inequality?

Comment: @N-C: When you take square roots you will get $-1$. If you did get $0$ then something must have gone wrong because correlation can indeed be negative.

Comment: @user21820 I must be missing something. If we start out with $0 \leq p^2 \leq 1$, and we take the square root of each part of that inequality, we get $\sqrt{0}=0$ $\sqrt{1}=1$ $\sqrt{p^2}=p$. How does that negative come in?

Comment: @N-C: Yes you're not allowed to take square-roots of both sides of an inequality just like that. For example $1^2 < (-2)^2$ but certainly $1 > -2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14664/discussion-between-n-c-and-user21820).

Comment: The CS inequality shows that $\rho^2\le 1$. This is equivalent to saying that $-1\le \rho\le 1$.